# Voltage expression in a circuit

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, voltage-divider

What would be the voltage V1?
I tried voltage divider :

V1 = (R1+R2/(R1+R2)+(4 R0+ R3 +RT) )

[image: Circuit]

Comment: Please show a bit of your own effort in solving this. Don't be afraid to make mistakes, but we are not just giving the answers to your homework.

Comment: @Douwe66 This isn't a question in my HW its a step that I need to analyze other questions, I did try it and I already have an answer but it is wrong, but as you suggested I have edited the question with my answer.

Comment: @user3052793 I just tried to solve it. can you check whether I got correct answer or not. [see this](https://imgur.com/a/omDIK). (I'm a student)

Comment: @KrishnShweta Alright I will solve again and compare. Much appreciated.

Comment: @user3052793 Really? Is it correct?

Comment: @KrshnShweta. I'm sorry but it is not correct, see my answer and use that as a starting point... You should at least have a minus sign somewhere in your final answer.

Comment: @Douwe66 Opps!! Okay :) I'll try again.

Answer (score 2):

As the voltage V1 does not have a common node with Vs, you can not simply use one voltage divider formula, you actually have 2 voltage dividers. 
By redrawing the circuit that becomes more clear:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhC3GGm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So what you need to do is calculate the voltage of both voltage dividers. The voltage difference between the two dividers is V1.

Comment: by 2 voltage dividers, you mean the upper part and the lower part of the circuit? I don't know which voltage  difference to compute.

Comment: No, in my picture the branch on the right and the one on the left are both voltage dividers. The voltage between R3 and R1 is the first voltage to calculate and the voltage between R0 and R2 is the second voltage. V1 is the difference between those voltages...